# Redistributing Connected Routes into an OSPF Instance on a Nexus 7010

Tags: ospf

So, I'm trying to redistribute six routes into OSPF with the default type and metric, but I seem to be having a good deal of trouble figuring this out. I have done extensive research, but am still struggling. My situation is as follows:

Router B is receiving six routes from Router C via EIGRP. Three of the EIGRP routes are classful (5.0.0.0/8, 145.5.0.0/16, 205.5.5.0/24) and three are classless (6.0.0.0/12, 146.6.0.0/20, 206.6.6.0/28). 
How can I redistribute these routes into an OSPF using default type and metric?

Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with redistributing the eigrp network into ospf, maybe you are trying to redistribute into a stub or totally stub area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following configuration

Router ospf *process id*
redistribute Eigrp *autonomous systemID* subnets

That should do it. this router will redistribute those EIGRP routes as external OSPF routes denoted by **O E2** in routing table with AD of 110 and metric value calculated by dividing default reference bandwidth with route bandwith that it has used till the end of this redistributing router.You can see it as external links in OSPF database tyoe-5 LSA.